# Weird projection using custom panorama and large equirectengular file

Tags: api, google-street-view, panoramas

I'll try to explain my problem :

I'm creating a custom panorama with the Street View API, I cut my panorama image by 512px tiles (my panorama is always a multiple of 512px).

It's render well, in most case :
http://postimg.org/image/vdrre7qt7/

But, when I'm using large panorama, it's render like this : 
http://postimg.org/image/5uxo0nof7/

This effect disapear when I zoom in.

On mobile, whatever the panorama size is, it's render the same (and have to zoom in to 3 or 4 zoom value to have it right).

Here is my code (size.w and size.h are the panorama dimension):

```
   var streetViewPanoramaData = {
            links: [],
            copyright: 'Stuff',
            tiles: {
                tileSize: new google.maps.Size(512, 512), 
                worldSize: new google.maps.Size(size.w, size.h),
                centerHeading: 0,
                getTileUrl: t.getCustomPanoramaTileUrl
            }
        };

        streetViewPanoramaData["location"] = {
            pano: panoID,
            description: "Custom Panorama",
            latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(37.556429, -122.050745)
        };
```

Here is the getCustomePanoramaTileURL

```
 this.getCustomPanoramaTileUrl = function(panoID, zoom, tileX, tileY) {
    // Return a pano image given the panoID.

    return "/the/directory/" + panoID + '/' + 0 + '_' + tileX + '_' + tileY + '.jpg';
}
```

"/the/directory/panoID" contain my tiles.

Any lead will be appreciate :)

Comment: to complete, for smaller panorama, if I reduce my browser size, the weird projection occured. It look like a "mini planet" projection but with missing pixels....

Answer (score 0):

I think, I had exactly the same problem. It took me hours to solve it.

So, the problem is, that you create only 1 image and split it into tiles.

Google requires multiple images, split into tiles - one image for each zoom level.

You need to create each version of the panorama for successive 1/2 height 1/2 width sizes until the panorama fits into one tile.

For example, if you have a panorama of 6000 * 3000 pixels and you use a 512 * 512 tile size, you will need to create:

- panorama 6000 * 3000 (12*6 tiles)
- panorama 3000 * 1500 (6*3 tiles)
- panorama 1500 * 750 (3*2 tiles)
- panorama 750 * 375 (2*1 tiles)
- panorama 375 * 187 (1*1 tile)

This is little PHP script I use to generate tiles:

```
// util function used below
function resize_image($old_src, $new_src, $new_width, $new_height=null)
{
    $src=imagecreatefromjpeg($old_src);
    list($width, $height)=getimagesize($old_src);
    $new_height = $new_height ? $new_height : round(($height/$width)*$new_width);
    $tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

    if (file_exists($new_src))
        unlink($new_src);

    imagejpeg($tmp, $new_src, 85);
}

$pano="/path/to/your/panorama.jpg";
$tiles_dir="/directory/where/you/want/to/place/tiles";
$crop_width=$crop_height=500; // your tiles size

$zooms=array(8000, 4000, 2000, 1000, 500); // I have 8000*4000 image, so I set sizes manually
$zooms=array_reverse($zooms);

foreach ($zooms as $zoom_level=>$zoom_width)
{
    $name=str_replace('.jpg', '', basename($pano));

    $zoom_dir=$tiles_dir.'/'.$name.'/'.$zoom_level;
    if (!is_dir($zoom_dir))
        mkdir($zoom_dir, 0777, true);

    $temp_image_src=sys_get_temp_dir().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.uniqid();
    resize_image($pano, $temp_image_src, $zoom_width); // my own function that resizes image

    $img = new Imagick($temp_image_src);
    $imgHeight=$img->getImageHeight();
    $imgWidth=$img->getImageWidth();

    $crop_width_num_times=ceil($imgWidth/$crop_width);
    $crop_height_num_times=ceil($imgHeight/$crop_height);
    $counter_x=0;
    for ($i=0; $i<$crop_width_num_times; $i++)
    {
        $counter_y=0;
        for ($j=0; $j<$crop_height_num_times; $j++)
        {
            $img = new Imagick($temp_image_src);
            $x=($i*$crop_width);
            $y=($j*$crop_height);
            $img->cropImage($crop_width, $crop_height, $x, $y);
            $data=$img->getImageBlob();

            for ($z=0; $z<=5; $z++)
            {
                $newFileName=$zoom_dir."/".$counter_x."_".$counter_y.".jpg";
                $result=file_put_contents($newFileName, $data);
            }

            $counter_y++;
        }

        $counter_x++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your message. Since my post I figured it out too, I'm using Image Magick to create the tiles and doing :
- crop 512px tiles in the original file
- crop 1024px tiles in the original file then shrink it to 512px
- crop 2048px tiles in the original file then shring it to 512px
- crop 4096px tiles ....

and so on

It take a looooot of time to process ( 4 min for a 8000*4000 image).

If you a have a faster solution using PHP or Imagick in command line... :)